# SQLite with inner select

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, select

I need to construct a SQLite statement based on the below table schema.  The ParentEventInfoID is mapping to other items in the same table.

Table Name EventInfo:
_id, Name, Description, ParentEventInfoID, SortId

Part of the requirements for the query needs perform a where clause on Name and Description, which I don't have a problem with:

```
SELECT * FROM EventInfo 
   Where Name LIKE "%search text%" OR 
         Description LIKE "%search text%" 
ORDER BY SortId;
```

The part i'm having trouble with is I need to also include the parent item for an entry.  Below is a statement that returns all the matches for the LIKE's, but only one parent item even though I know I should have more:

```
SELECT * FROM EventInfo 
    Where Name LIKE "%search text%" OR 
          Description LIKE "%search text%" OR 
          _id = (SELECT ParentEventInfoID FROM EventInfo
                   Where (Name LIKE "%search text%" OR 
                          Description LIKE "%search text%") 
ORDER BY SortId
```

I haven't done a ton of SQL in a while and I'm feeling very rusty.  Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: replace the `=` after _id with `IN`

Comment: @MillerKoijam That did the trick!  Do you think this is the most efficient way to build like this?

Comment: There should be better query. I think we can avoid the like clause in the inner query as we are hitting the same table

Comment: Yeah that's the part I don't like.  Seem redundant.  But in the meantime your solution got it working for me.  If you want to put it as an answer I'll accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT * FROM EventInfo 
    Where Name LIKE "%search text%" OR 
          Description LIKE "%search text%" OR 
          _id IN (SELECT ParentEventInfoID FROM EventInfo
                   Where (Name LIKE "%search text%" OR 
                          Description LIKE "%search text%") 
ORDER BY SortId
```

But there should be better query that avoid like clause in the inner query.

Comment: Perfect.  Thanks for the help.  I would like to find a more efficient statement, but this keeps me going.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You can use SELF JOINS

```
SELECT E1.* FROM EventInfo E1
LEFT JOIN EventInfo E2
ON E1._id =E2.ParentEventInfoID 
Where Name LIKE "%search text%" OR 
      Description LIKE "%search text%" OR  
ORDER BY E1.SortId
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I just tried this and it ends up with the same result as my first statement with out the inner select.